# Delegate CanActivate() to Component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have tens of components in my angular(4) application.

Uses can only access which have access permission.

- for example UserA can access DashboardComponent, but userB not.

Some components check authorization with parameter.

- for example UserA can access VisualizeComponent with parameter 1, but can not access with parameter 2.

There are many type of Access grant or deny strategy.

So I imagine what about delegate CanActivate method to each component, because each component is the best place to check the access according to it's purpose.

I know usually people implements CanActivate at Services like below.

```
@Injectable()
export class AccessGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
              state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

   route.component.canActivate(route, state); // <----- HERE

   return true;
  }
}
```

Now can I call some method at line 6?
I want to implement CanActivate to all of my components and let them have their own guard login in that method. so do i easily put guard logic close to component's business logic.

Answer (score -2):

1. Try to add some sessionService which must store information about parameters which are responsible for access, add a method about your giving access logic.
2. Add apropriate methods

   ```
   @Injectable()
   export class AccessGuard implements CanActivate { canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
   constructor(private sessionService:SessionService) {}
   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
       return this.sessionService:SessionService.isAuthenticated();
   }}}
   ```

   3. For components and pages add router config for example
      {path: 'dashboard-page, component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]},

I hope it will help

Comment: I think this answer (even though it does work) does not explain how to delegate the business logic to the **component**. `route.component` seems to be a function and not the class itself.